# What's the difference between begin transaction vs. begin work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw in SQL Server about the transaction part it has following statements:

- begin transaction or begin work
- commit transaction or commit work
- rollback transaction or commit work

I used transaction set statements in my work, but why there are work statements here?
Are they same? If not, what the difference between them?

Comment: I think BEGIN WORK is with IBM's sql. Begin Tran/ Begin Transaction is used with MS's TSQL

Answer (score 3):

- According to [Microsoft's SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-work-transact-sql), there is no support for `BEGIN WORK`, instead use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (which also supports *named* transactions).

  - [The token `BEGIN` (by itself) denotes a statement-block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql) and is completely unrelated to transactions.
- Curiously, while SQL Server **does not** support `BEGIN WORK`, SQL Server *does* support [`COMMIT WORK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-work-transact-sql) and [`ROLLBACK WORK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-work-transact-sql).

  - [`COMMIT WORK` has identical semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-work-transact-sql) to `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.
  - [`ROLLBACK WORK` has identical semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-work-transact-sql) to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.
- Also curiously, [the ISO SQL-2016][6] [grammar uses `START TRANSACTION` with `COMMIT WORK` and `ROLLBACK WORK`](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html#_17_transaction_management) which is a strangely inconsistent use of language keywords.

  - SQL Server 2017+ and Azure SQL does seem to support `START WORK` though SSMS does not recognize the syntax.

### ISO SQL (2016) vs T-SQL (MS SQL Server)

|  | ISO SQL | T-SQL (SQL Server) | [Effect on `@@TRANCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Transactions** |  |  |  |
| Begin a transaction | `START TRANSACTION` | `BEGIN TRANSACTION` | `+ 1` |
| Commit a transaction | `COMMIT WORK` | `COMMIT TRANSACTION` | `- 1` |
| Rollback a transaction | `ROLLBACK WORK` | `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` | `= 0` |
| **Savepoints** |  |  |  |
| Create a savepoint | `SAVEPOINT` | `SAVE TRANSACTION` | (No effect) |
| Release a savepoint | `RELEASE SAVEPOINT` | (Not supported) | (No effect) |
| Rollback to savepoint | `ROLLBACK WORK TO SAVEPOINT` | `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` | (No effect) |

### Syntax Support in SQL Server 2016 and later, and Azure SQL

- NOTE: This does not necessarily include *Azure Synapse*, *SQL Server Parallel Data Warehouse*, and *Analytics Platform System*.

| T-SQL Syntax | Semantics |
| --- | --- |
| **Similar and Ambiguous syntax:** | These commands are easily confused for `TRANSACTION` control statements, but in SQL Server are completely unrelated to `TRANSACTIONS`. |
| `BEGIN` | `BEGIN`, by itself, without any following `TRAN` or `TRANSACTION` keyword, denotes a statement block terminated by `END`. |
| `START` | Undocumented, but recognized by SSMS, curiously. |
| **Start a transaction:** |  |
| `BEGIN WORK` | *Not supported by SQL Server* |
| `START WORK` | *Not supported by SQL Server* |
| `START TRANSACTION` | *Not supported by SQL Server* |
| `BEGIN TRAN` | Identical to `BEGIN TRANSACTION` |
| `BEGIN TRAN <transaction_name>` | Identical to `BEGIN TRANSACTION <transaction_name>`. `transaction_name` can also be a `@variable` containing the transaction name. Named transactions are mostly used with nested transactions, but committing an inner transaction is a NOOP and only the outermost transaction can be used with `ROLLBACK` |
| `BEGIN TRANSACTION` | Starts an unnamed transaction. |
| `BEGIN TRANSACTION <transaction_name>` | `transaction_name` can also be a `@variable` containing the transaction name. |
| **Commit a transaction** |  |
| `COMMIT` | Identical to `COMMIT TRANSACTION` |
| `COMMIT WORK` | Identical to `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. ISO SQL compliant. |
| `COMMIT TRAN` | Identical to `COMMIT TRANSACTION` |
| `COMMIT TRAN <transaction_name>` | Identical to `COMMIT TRANSACTION <transaction_name>`. `transaction_name` can also be a `@variable` containing the transaction name. |
| `COMMIT TRANSACTION` | Commits an unnamed transaction started with `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. Cannot be used to create a savepoint (use `SAVE TRANSACTION` for that). |
| `COMMIT TRANSACTION <transaction_name>` | Commits a named transaction started with `BEGIN TRANSACTION <transaction_name>`. Cannot be used to create a savepoint (use `SAVE TRANSACTION <savepoint_name>` for that). Committing a nested transaction is a no-op in SQL Server: inner/nested changes are only committed when the outermost transaction is committed. |
| **Rollback a transaction** |  |
| `ROLLBACK` | Identical to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. |
| `ROLLBACK WORK` | Identical to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. ISO SQL compliant. |
| `ROLLBACK TRAN` | Identical to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. |
| `ROLLBACK TRAN <transaction_name>` | Identical to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION <transaction_name>`. `transaction_name` can also be a `@variable` containing the transaction name. |
| `ROLLBACK TRAN <savepoint_name>` | Identical to `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION <savepoint_name>`. `savepoint_name` can also be a `@variable` containing the savepoint name. |
| `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` | Rolls back the current explicit or implicit transaction. |
| `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION <transaction_name>` | Rolls back a named transaction. `transaction_name` *must* be the outermost transaction's name when working with nested transactions. |
| `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION <savepoint_name>` | `savepoint_name` must have been previously created with `SAVE TRANSACTION <savepoint_name>` (this is how the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` command for transactions vs. savepoints is disambiguated). |